# remove substring with space

Tags: python-3.x, regex, data-cleaning

I want to convert bellow string

```
JS00001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -5 28232 0 aVR
```

to this string in python

```
-5 28232 0 aVR
```

I can do that with this code

```
regex = r'JS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 '
s = re.sub(regex,"",'JS00001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 517 -22376 0 III')
```

but it can't removes this part

```
JS00001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0
```

pay attention this point that is Js00001 its not constant each different in each row of dataframe (517 -22376 too).

please help me.

Comment: You need to escape `+` to make it `16\+24`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you want the last 4 values of the string. You can do this without regex, like so:

```py
string = r"JS00001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -5 28232 0 aVR"
last_four_values = string.split(maxsplit=5)[-1] 
last_four_values = " ".join(string.split()[-4:]) # Or another way
print(last_four_values)
```

Output:

```
-5 28232 0 aVR
```

What other strings do you need to convert?

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 1):

`.*(-5 28232 0 aVR)` -> This regex will match entire string and also required string is captured with the help of `()` stored it in backreference \1 and It has replaced the entire string and assigned it to the variable result. I have implemented it in the following code.

```
import re

regex = r".*(-5 28232 0 aVR)"

test_str = "JS00001.mat 16+24 1000/mV 16 0 -5 28232 0 aVR"

subst = "\\1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

if result:
    print (result)


 # Ouput
  
 -5 28232 0 aVR
```

Comment: while I think regex are a possible solution here, a bit of explanation might be useful - OP tried regex as well but did not succeed - why? what do you do differently?

Comment: What's the meaning of OP ?

Comment: original poster, meaning the person that asked the question

Comment: I have just matched the entire string with my regex pattern and also captured the required string in backreferece \1. After capturing ,I have replace the entire string with captured one and  assigned it to result variable. and that's how I was able to solve  the issue.

Comment: consider adding this to your answer. code-only answers end up in the review queue, so no matter how self-explanatory or well-commented they are, someone (a human) is supposed to check them.

Comment: Alright, I will do it .Thanks for the suggestion.